# Are there any Bluetooth 4.0 (LE capable) USB adapters that support MacOS/Linux/Unix?

Tags: bluetooth, usb, bluetooth-lowenergy, adapter, compatibility

I’m working on a project that uses BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) protocols for transferring data and am currently limited to my MacBook due to some Admin permission constraints on my work machine (running Windows).

I need to find a USB adapter that supports Bluetooth 4.0 Tx/Rx, however I am ONLY finding these dongles that solely support Windows distros. So my question:

1) Why is this? Is Bluetooth SIG or at least BLE somehow a propriety protocol patented or somehow bound to Microsoft? I mean, there exist iOS libraries for high-level BLE management, so...

2) Am I just missing the product I’m looking for and there are such accessories compatible with a Unix based OS?

Answer (score 0):

Who said USB dongles only support Windows? On the contrary, I haven't heard about a single USB dongle that doesn't support Linux. Bluetooth SIG has defined and specified HCI over USB and every device uses that protocol (however some device specific code is often needed to initialize the device). See a list of some tested devices at https://github.com/50ButtonsEach/fliclib-linux-hci/blob/master/README.md#bluetooth-controllers. Those should work with Mac OS X as well, but if the computer already has a built in Bluetooth chip you might need to adjust the currently used device.